# create class diagram from sequence diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram, visual-paradigm

I have a sequence diagram, and I would like to create a class diagram from it.

This is the sequence diagram:

[image]

I'm struggling with classes operations (which class should I give what operations)

Comment: should actor be added to class diagram?

Comment: You can as well edit your question. As long as you don't start with "and one more"...

Comment: Hi! Does the answer provide you the explanations you need, or are there still unclear points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive the class from the life line. Each is an instance of a class.  With the used notation you can say that the title corresponds to the class name directly. The actor is some informal compromise and is not a class.

The messages towards a life line correspond to operations of the class. E.g. `ViewBookForm` has `onClick()`.

In any case you can pinpoint only those operations you have in the diagram. And you can't find out the atributes. So your classes will be skeletons only.

Comment: Maybe worth to mention the [ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary) stereotypes?

Comment: @Christophe Nope. There's a lot one could say. This is a simple question and a simple answer....